# Can Matsumoto's theorem for the symmetric group be proved using a monovariant?

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations, symmetric-groups, algebraic-combinatorics, coxeter-groups

This is a question that can be asked for any Coxeter group, but for the sake of simplicity I will restrict myself to symmetric groups. Recall the main definitions:

Let $n$ be a nonnegative integer. The symmetric group $S_n$ consists of the permutations of the set $\left[n\right] := \left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}$. For each $i \in \left[n-1\right]$, we let $s_i$ be the $i$-th *simple transposition*; this is the permutation in $S_n$ that swaps $i$ with $i+1$ while leaving all other elements of $\left[n\right]$ unchanged. It is well-known that the symmetric group $S_n$ can be presented as the group with generators $s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_{n-1}$ and relations

- $s_i^2 = 1$ for all $i \in \left[n-1\right]$,
- $s_i s_j = s_j s_i$ for all $i,j \in \left[n-1\right]$ satisfying $\left|i-j\right| > 1$,
- $s_i s_{i+1} s_i = s_{i+1} s_i s_{i+1}$ for all $i \in \left[n-2\right]$.

This is known as the *Coxeter-Moore presentation* of $S_n$.

Let us take a look at the combinatorics of this presentation. If $w \in S_n$, then

- a *Coxeter word* for $w$ shall mean a tuple $\left(i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_k\right) \in \left[n-1\right]^k$ satisfying $w = s_{i_1} s_{i_2} \ldots s_{i_k}$;
- a *reduced word* for $w$ shall mean a Coxeter word for $w$ that has the smallest length among all Coxeter words for $w$.

For example, the cycle $\left(1,2,3\right)$ has reduced word $s_1 s_2$ and a (non-reduced) Coxeter word $s_3 s_1 s_3 s_2$. (The typical permutation has many reduced words and infinitely many Coxeter words.)

Given a reduced word $\mathbf{i} = \left(i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_k\right)$ of $w$, we can obtain other reduced words of $w$ by the following transformations:

- We can pick two adjacent entries $i_u$ and $i_{u+1}$ of $\mathbf{i}$ that satisfy $\left|i_u - i_{u+1}\right| > 1$, and swap them. This is called a *commutation move*; for example, we can use such a move to transform $\left(1,2,3,1,2\right)$ into $\left(1,2,1,3,2\right)$.
- We can pick three adjacent entries $i_u$, $i_{u+1}$ and $i_{u+2}$ of $\mathbf{i}$ that satisfy $i_u = i_{u+2} = i_{u+1} \pm 1$, and replace them by $i_{u+1}$, $i_u$ and $i_{u+1}$, respectively. This is called a *braid move*; for example, we can use such a move to transform $\left(1,2,1,3,2\right)$ into $\left(2,1,2,3,2\right)$, and we can use another such move to transform this result further into $\left(2,1,3,2,3\right)$.

> **Theorem (Matsumoto's theorem for the symmetric group).** Let $w \in S_n$. Then, any two reduced words of $w$ can be transformed into one another by a sequence of commutation moves and braid moves.

This theorem is often illustrated by drawing the graph whose vertices are the reduced words of a given $w \in S_n$, with two vertices $\mathbf{i}$ and $\mathbf{j}$ being joined by an edge if the reduced word $\mathbf{j}$ can be obtained from $\mathbf{i}$ by a single commutation move or braid move. Page 6 of [Yuval Roichman's SLC67 slides](http://emis.impa.br/EMIS/journals/SLC/wpapers/s67vortrag/roichman.pdf) shows such a graph.

An elementary proof of Matsumoto's theorem appears, e.g., in [the LLPT notes](http://web.math.ku.dk/%7Ethorup/notes/sympol.pdf) (Chapter SYM, Proposition (2.6)). Most texts on Coxeter groups prove it as well, in one or the other (usually more general) form. Some (I believe) derive it from the PBW property of the Hecke algebra. However, these proofs (to my knowledge) are rather tricky, and appear to rely on massaging the reduced words until they either begin or end with the same letter. (Not sure about the Hecke-based proof, but the proof in the LLPT notes definitely works this way.)

I am a bit surprised that the seemingly more natural *monovariant* approach is never used:

- assigning a number (or some other kind of object in a totally ordered set) to each reduced word (for example, we could assign $\sum_{j=1}^k j^2 i_j$ to the reduced word $\left(i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_k\right)$);
- then showing that if $\mathbf{i}$ is any reduced word, then we can apply a braid or commutation move to $\mathbf{i}$ that decreases this number, unless $\mathbf{i}$ has some specific property that characterizes it uniquely (there are several known choices of "canonical" reduced word for a permutation $w$ -- it could be one of them, or a new one);
- then concluding by the monovariance principle (as the set of reduced expressions of $w$ is finite).

(Intuitively, this sort of reasoning is the first thing one might try. After all, one can think of transforming reduced words as pulling a string around the surface of a permutahedron, while keeping the ends of the string fixed on two vertices; the permutahedron being convex, there should be a way to pull it "all the way down" without it getting stuck. The monovariant would then be responsible for defining the meaning of "down".)

Alternatively, and to some extent equivalently, I'm surprised to have never seen a [diamond lemma](https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/%7Egrinberg/algebra/diamond-talk.pdf) argument for the theorem.

> **Question:** Do such proofs of Matsumoto's theorem exist? Or are there some obstructions to them?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have seen it proved that the kind of rewriting system you are suggesting is confluence and terminating.  I think maybe Ronan uses this approach even if he doesn't say the word complete rewriting system but it may be somewhere else.  You might look at Tits original proof

Comment: Do you just want finite Coxeter groups?  Googling complete rewriting system and Coxeter groups gives lots of hits

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: I'm specifically interested in symmetric groups, so yes, finite suffices for me. Do you have a specific reference? Note that I'm not suggesting a specific complete rewriting system; I feel that knowing such a system would be 90% of the answer.

Comment: For the symmetric group, I think one could derive a proof of this type pretty easily using results from Sami Assaf's paper "A inversion statistic for reduced words" https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.01281

Comment: You might look at chapter 2 of Ronan's lectures on buildings.  He doesn't quite use the formulation of complete rewriting systems but he does use the geometry of the Coxeter complex (so like your permutohedron) to tell you when to get the normal fom and he has a later section of the chapter where he looks at the graph of all reduced words and allows only braid moves

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: Thanks for reminding me of Tits' paper (Jacques Tits, *Le problème des mots dans les groupes de Coxeter*, pp. 503--513 in his *Oeuvres* Volume II) -- it has a proof that is simpler than the one in the LLPT notes, and in particular lends itself to splitting into homework problems for my combinatorics class!

Comment: @ZacharyHamaker: Ah, I forgot about that paper. Just in case, do you know how well this particular paper has been verified?

Comment: @darijgrinberg I've read the paper carefully. the stated Theorems are all correct. a bit of care might be required to make the proof you desire self-contained

Comment: On a tangential note, I'd like to try to persuade you against using the term "Coxeter word".  In the broader context of combinatorial group theory, we just have "words" and perhaps "reduced words".  If you were going to modify the noun "word" in some way, the best thing would be to name the alphabet.  After all, in Coxeter groups, there are other good choices of alphabets, so saying "Coxeter word" doesn't really help much.  Also, saying "Coxeter word" leans in the direction of confusing people about "Coxeter elements".

Comment: My favorite proof of this property uses the fact that the weak order is a lattice.  (That fact is not too hard to prove, especially for the symmetric group.)  From that point of view, reduced words for $w$ are just maximal chains from the identity to $w$.  Instead of always moving down in some arbitrary notion of "down" (which must necessarily really be "sideways" on the permutohedron), the proof works by moving two chains closer to each other, in terms of how many initial edges they share.

Comment: The proof I have in mind is probably equivalent to the "massaging" Darij doesn't like, but the whole point is that the lattice property makes it quite simple to make the words start with the same letter.  (As part of the argument, you need to know something about rank-2 Coxeter groups, but what could be more natural than having a proof about Coxeter groups come down to a rank-2 fact?)

Comment: @NathanReading: It's not that I don't like the proof (particularly since I've found it explained more naturally in Tits' original paper); I'm just surprised about its seeming monopoly (well, apart from Sami Assaf's paper). But you made me wonder: Does that lattice argument apply to maximal chains in other lattices?

Comment: @darijgrinberg:  Yes, the natural setting for the more general arguments is a class of lattices called "polygonal" lattices.  I have written about this in a book chapter "Lattice Theory of the Poset of Regions" available as paper #35 on http://nreading.math.ncsu.edu/papers/ (see particularly Section 9-6).  A "polygon" in a lattice is an interval that looks like a union of two chains, disjoint except at their top and bottom elements.  A lattice is polygonal if it has as many polygons as it could possibly have (as made precise in Definition 9-6.1).  Lemma 9-6.3 is the relevant result.

Comment: @NathanReading: Thanks, this looks highly explanatory! (Though the link doesn't seem to work -- but I've gotten used to NCSU servers not being very responsive. The published version is at https://sci-hub.se/10.1007/978-3-319-44236-5_9 .)

Comment: I think this link will work:   http://nreadin.math.ncsu.edu/papers .  (I made the silly mistake of spelling my own name correctly in the earlier link.  The fact that my NCSU user id is nreadin has been the source of many headaches for me.)

Answer (score 3):

Adriano Garsia gives a proof of essentially this form in his book ["The Saga of Reduced Factorizations of Elements of the Symmetric Group"](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/%7Egarsia/somepapers/saga.pdf).
See Theorem 1.1.2 for details. In particular, Garsia's argument does **not** rely on the exchange lemma.
Basically, the idea is to show the minimal value $i$ occuring in a reduced word can be made to occur once.
Then separating the reduced word into two, $(\textbf{a},i,\textbf{b})$ we can do the same to $\textbf{a},\textbf{b}$ to obtain $(\dots,i+1,\dots,i,\dots, i+1,\dots)$ and so on.
Eventually this procedure results in a canonical form.
If the first step can be interpreted using a monovariant argument, the whole proof can be viewed through that lense.